# div inside script html W3C

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to load some scripts into a page and got a warning on the W3C validator which corresponds to this code:

```
XHTML 1.0 Transitional
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("area[rel^='Photo']").Photo();
$(".gallery:..: false});
.
.
.
$("#custom_content a[rel^='Photo']:last").Photo({
custom_markup: '<div id="bsap_12" class="bsap_d49a0984d0f377271"></div><div id="bsap_15" class="bsarocks bsap_d49a0984d0f377271" style="height:260px"></div><div id="bsap_13" class="bsap_d49a0984d0f377271"></div>',
changepicturecallback: function(){ _bsap.exec(); }
});
});
</script>
```

Error: document type does not allow element "div" here
Error: document type does not allow element "div" here
Error: document type does not allow element "div" here
Error: document type does not allow element "div" here
(four times)
What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the validator may interpret html inside javascript as html and validate it in place. This is likely to cause errors. To avoid this, you can mark it as [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    //<![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("area[rel^='Photo']").Photo();
    $(".gallery:..: false});
    .
    .
    .
    $("#custom_content a[rel^='Photo']:last").Photo({
    custom_markup: '<div id="bsap_12" class="bsap_d49a0984d0f377271"></div><div id="bsap_15" class="bsarocks bsap_d49a0984d0f377271" style="height:260px"></div><div id="bsap_13" class="bsap_d49a0984d0f377271"></div>',
    changepicturecallback: function(){ _bsap.exec(); }
    });
    });
    //]]>
    </script>
```

That should validate without the errors. [Here's more on the subject](http://help.simplytestable.com/errors/html-validation/document-type-does-not-allow-element-x-here/document-type-does-not-allow-element-div-here/).